# Finding my swap partition

Tags: filesystem, swap, proc, df

It looks like I have 40 GB of swap:

```
wuser@wavesftwDell:~$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition       40959996        956    -1

wuser@wavesftwDell:~$ swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/rhel_krillin-swap           partition       40959996        956    -1
```

But I cannot find this in `df` output or gparted:

```
wuser@wavesftwDell:~$ df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              1947052        12    1947040   1% /dev
tmpfs              391628      1324     390304   1% /run
/dev/sda5        71931216  24346148   43908092  36% /
none                    4         0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                 5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
none              1958140       224    1957916   1% /run/shm
none               102400        60     102340   1% /run/user
/dev/sdg1      3906983932    185496 3906798436   1% /home/wuser/lala
/dev/sdb1       961301832 175093504  737353904  20% /media/wuser/Boromir1TBv2
/dev/sda1          508588    153804     354784  31% /media/wuser/ec3f56a6-ed56-4bfd-bdb5-0d27a0fa1a76
```

[image]

Why does my swap partition not show up?

Answer (score 4):

I see you are using LVM partitions.

df command never shows swap partitions because they are not a file system partition.
You can check your existing Logical Volumes with `lvs` command and check your device mapper (dm-X) devices witch `ls -l /dev/mapper/` or `dmsetup ls`

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Disk Utility.
2. In the left column, look for your hard disk, and click on it.
3. In the right column, see if you can find "Swap". If so, you have swap enabled; you can click on that portion to see details.

Alternately, open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T, and type swapon -s; if you see a line like the below, with statistics, swap is enabled:

[image]